# MongoDB Official GoLang Driver Comparision Operator

Tags: mongodb, go, logic

Im attempting to use Go to Learn Mongo DB while I migrate a project from MySQL to Mongo. One of the issues I am having is understanding how to perform a comparsion query in Mongo VIA the Official Mongo DB Driver. I can write the same query via MongoDB Compass and it work flawlessly, but I can't figure out how to translate that to a viable query in the driver.

So here is the query

```
{cached_until: {$lt:1599090092 }}
```

It is super simple, the cached_until attribute is a unix timestamp. When I inserted the record, I grabbed the current ts and the cached until property to it and then performed the insert. Here is some data.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f4ed5a9272d650f55ee822a"
    },
    "id": {
        "$numberLong": "2116190568"
    },
    "name": "John Gustafson",
    "corporation_id": {
        "$numberLong": "98522659"
    },
    "alliance_id": {
        "$numberLong": "99003214"
    },
    "security_status": 2.817923833,
    "not_modified_count": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
    },
    "update_priority": {
        "$numberLong": "0"
    },
    "etag": "\"f3a0614b043a556b02d0e53372d0bd0c5bfa5516b9ecf003b5d4fd64\"",
    "cached_until": {
        "$numberLong": "1599072490"
    },
    "created_at": {
        "$numberLong": "1599002025"
    },
    "updated_at": {
        "$numberLong": "1599002025"
    }
}
```

Using the above query, the above document is returned from Mongo, but if i translate that to Go using the Official Mongo DB Go Driver,

```
results, err := app.MongoDB.Collection("characters").Find(ctx, bson.D{bson.E{Key: "cached_until", Value: bson.E{Key: "$lt", Value: time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24).Unix()}}})
                    if err != nil {
                        return err
                    }

                    fmt.Println(results.RemainingBatchLength())
```

The number 0 is outputted. I've been fighting this for the past day or so and Im honestly not sure what i am doing wrong. This started with full fledge timestamp, but then I tried to use unix timestamps and when my comparisons wrong, I resorted to search stack and can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misread the documentation.

The filter I was setting was structured incorrectly, the following:

```
bson.D{bson.E{Key: "cached_until", Value: bson.E{Key: "$lt", Value: time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24).Unix()}}}
```

should be:

```
bson.D{bson.E{Key: "cached_until", Value: bson.D{bson.E{Key: "$lt", Value: time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24).Unix()}}}}
```

The difference is when setting the the value `cached_until`. I was setting `Value: bson.E{Key: COlumn, Value: value}` instead of `Value: bson.D{bson.E{Key: Operator, Value: value}}`